Are W-spaces with countable pseudocharacter first countable?
Cross-post of a question originally asked by Almanzoris on Mathematics Stack Exchange.
A topological space $X$ is called W-space if P1 has a winning strategy at each point $x \in X$ for the following game defined by Gruenhage in DOI 10.1016/0016-660X(76)90024-6:

During each round $n < \omega$, P1 chooses some neighborhood $U_n$ of $x$, then P2 chooses some point $p_n \in U_n$. P1 wins provided the sequence $p_n$ converges to $x$; P2 wins otherwise.

Is every W-space with countable pseudocharacter (each point is a countable intersection of open sets) first countable?

Note: π-Base, Search for ?W-space+Has points $G_\delta$+~First countable reveals a single candidate for a counter-example, the Ping-Wu Group defined in Section 4 of A Lindelöf group with non-Lindelöf square (Ping, Wu).

No, counterexamples abound. For instance, Uspenskii constructed (see http://dml.cz/dmlcz/106296), for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$, a dense subspace $X$ of the $\Sigma$-product of $[0,1]^\kappa$, which is the union of countably many closed discrete sets (hence every subset of X, not just every singleton, is a $G_\delta$-set). Now, it is easy to see that every subspace of a W-space is a W-space and it is well-known that the W-property is preserved by $\Sigma$-products (see Gary Gruenhage’s paper where W-spaces where originally defined). Finally, if $\kappa >\mathfrak{c}$ then X is not first-countable because every first-countable ccc Hausdorff space has cardinality at most continuum (actually if one looks at the construction in detail it’s clear that X is not first-countable whenever $\kappa$ is uncountable).
